# Is keycloak-js vulnerable to XSS attacks?

Tags: keycloak, xss

Historically I've always used cookies (HTTP Only, Secure, Same-Site=strict) for my access tokens. In my application ecosystem I'm using a home-grown OAuth2 authorization server that assigns the access tokens to cookies, and everything is solid. My intent is to move away from this solution and use KeyCloak instead.

Ideally I would love to use the keycloak-js library to handle user logins. I like it for several reasons, not the least of which is that it completely decouples authentication and refresh flows from my backend services. At the moment the design of my OAuth2 server requires a unique token be minted for each specific backend service, which results in an architecture of application monoliths instead of micro-services. KeyCloak is intended to resolve this, generating a token that can be sent to a variety of services where access to each service is controlled by the token's rolls.

This brings me back to my original question, namely whether or not keycloak-js is vulnerable to XSS attacks. After all, all the token information is stored in the Keycloak instance variable. I've always viewed all JS code as being inherently vulnerable, however in this case I'm unclear of the exact degree of vulnerability. Given that Keycloak is providing this library for client-side authentication, it seems to me they wouldn't have designed it to be so vulnerable.

If I am using keycloak-js (and the Keycloak instance itself, ie `const keycloak = new Keycloak();`) as a local variable in a JS module, is it vulnerable to XSS attacks? What should I be concerned about in terms of protecting myself here?